# How to Load Multiple Recordsets in Excel to SQL using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I was trying to load an Excel sheet which contains multiple record sets - where each record set has the same header names - to SQL in SSIS.

I assigned a Data Flow Task in the Control Flow. Then in the Data Flow tab, started with the Excel Source, used a Data Conversion, then finally OLE DB Destination.

It worked, however in the SQL table it shows NULL values which represent the blank rows in the Excel sheet and also it shows duplicated records of the header names in the SQL. In total, my SQL table has 18 rows of records which is incorrect and I should only have 12 rows.

Could someone please advise how to remove the NULL values and the duplicated header names in the SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try conditional spit component and in that you can set output condition 1 as

```
 (column1=="Person" || ISNULL(column1))  && (column2=="Region"  || ISNULL(column1)) && (column3 =="type"  || ISNULL(column1))
```

Then other default output condition can be connected to destination to load data into table, which loads remaining records into database.